# Why were my flags declined?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, meta, declined-flags

This is kind of a meta-question *for* Meta Stack Exchange.

You may remember my question about a [Vietnamese to English translation issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361994).

I realized it wasn't suitable for Meta Stack Exchange, and because regular users can't delete questions with answers, I decided to flag for mods to delete it.

My first flag said:

> I realize now that this is not^1 really about SE, so I was wondering if I could have it deleted?

It was then declined, and I got this message:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I tried reflagging and changing my message to this just in case the first one was misinterpreted:

> I already flagged this post asking for deletion, but it was declined. Maybe they misinterpreted my flag? Anyway, could this post be deleted by a mod (I can't; it has an answer) because I now realize it is not about SE?

It was then again declined with the same automated message:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Why were my flags declined with such message when I was clearly asking a moderator to delete my question (which I can't do, therefore meaning that it requires a mod to).

What should I do now? The question is off-topic, low scored (perhaps I could mark as community wiki?), and leaves an unneeded black mark on my answer list for a small matter - so I feel like it would be best deleted. I see Journeyman Geek's point though, so I am a little confused. What would the best course of action be?

And I'm afraid to flag a third time, just in case it is declined and I pick up a flag ban.

---

I don't think this question is a duplicate of the FAQ on [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221) because I already know how deleting works and the criteria behind it, I just want to know why my flags to delete were rejected. The proposed dup question tells you to flag for mod deletion, which I did. It doesn't provide any further info.

^1 I flagged originally without the not - oops, I was typing fast and my mind jumped over a word. For clarity purpose, I meant to add a *not*.

Comment: Per the FAQ [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), section *If I flag my post with a request to delete it, what will happen?*, the standard policy is for mods to decline flags asking for deletion.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog No, it doesn't. I know how posts get deleted and the criteria behind that, I am just wondering my flag inquires were declined.

Comment: Contrary to the "The proposed dup question tells you to flag for mod deletion" you added in rev. 4, the proposed duplicate-target actually says: "If I flag my post with a request to delete it, what will happen? The standard policy for moderators is to decline such flags. The reasoning is as follows: …" That clearly covers your question of "why was my flag declined", unless you feel the reasons are inapplicable to this situation. In that case, you needed to explain why the reasons were inapplicable in your flag. The duplicate-target also clearly does **not** "tell you to flag for mod deletion".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The really funny thing is that I was having a conversation about multiple flags earlier today.

> There's nothing that annoys a mod more than repeated flagging of a thing. I vaguely remember there's folks who literally have been flagging the same post over years.
>
> It's been seen, we've decided what to do. Mods do talk and leave trails of what happened – and generally have long memories
>
> Much like how a bounty is spending 'reputation' to get attention (as opposed to an answer as many assumes) – the goal of a flag, accepted or declined, is to get a mod to take a look.

The point of a flag is to get a mod to take a look, so more than one flag from a user for a question is redundant.

While I didn't handle the flag(s) in question – we don't *generally* delete questions with positively scored, well-regarded answers through the mod deletion route. It is unfair for the person or people who answered.

So it's fine. It has been seen, judged, and one or more mods have decided not to delete it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What should I do now? Just leave it be? It is off-topic, low scored, and leaves an unneeded black mark on my answer list for a small matter - so I feel like it would be best deleted. I see your point though, so I am a little confused. What would the best course of action be?

Comment: just let it be.

Comment: Funny that you consider you advocate to not have your own answer deleted... ;)

Comment: One possible way out is for the author of the answer to self delete their contribution, as a sign of good will, and allow the OP to delete then their post. I mean how likely is that question and answer going to help future visitors? Moreover, the original question has recently  been closed as being **off topic**.

Comment: I didn't handle the flags. And well, I do  delete the post myself pretty often if I catch it myself/ Also, absolutely hilariously Its 4 am and I didn't realize the answer was mine. I'll take a look in the afternoon after I got some sleep

Answer (score 0):

> I realize now that this is really about SE, so I was wondering if I could have it deleted?

If it's about SE, it's [on-topic for Meta Stack Exchange](/help/whats-meta). That's a good reason to have it *not* deleted, so declining the flags is a logical response.

Comment: I believe they meant to say "this is **not** really about SE" which is further evidenced by the close reason.

Comment: Probably, but that's the **exact opposite** of what they wrote. If I say 'I want sugar in my coffee', what do you think I get? No sugar?

Comment: Please ignore that typo, I meant to add a *not*.

Comment: @Nai45 did you perhaps mean 'please don't ignore that typo'?

Comment: @Spevacus I flagged as original (without the not - oops) I was typing fast and my mind jumped over a word. And Glorfindel, *hilarious* <insert sarcasm.

Comment: I confused so.. am

Comment: @Nai45 Please consider being less hasty with your posts next time. You seem to be concerned about post quality. Quality takes time, effort and patience.

Comment: @Mast Thank you for the feedback. It is much appreciated. For which posts would you recommend being less hasty on? Thank you again.

Comment: @Nai45 All of them, naturally.